# Concatenate cells with different hyperlinks within a single cell

Tags: excel, vba, copy, concatenation, cell

I'm creating a spreadsheet that automatically put the hyperlinks from column D in the values of the column C, because I need to be able to copy the entire C Column with hyperlinks, and paste it elsewhere.

[image]

**The problem is:** If I copy the Column C and paste it anywhere else, it doesn't paste with a line break. It pastes like this:

```
textofcell1 textofcell2 textofcell3
```

**I need it to be like:**

```
textofcell1
textofcell2
textofcell3
```

It only works If I copy from Excel to Word, and from Word to anywhere else.

So I wanted to find a solution to concatenate all the cells into a single one, with line break (Alt + Enter) and the hyperlinks, like this:

[image]

Because from this single cell I can copy and paste it anywhere else, and it will respect the line break.

Can someone help? Or even if anyone has another solution to copy range C2 to C6 in a way the line break is respected and the hyperlinks follow.

Thank you :)

Comment: Any one cell can only have a single hyperlink

Comment: omg I just noticed this. Do you know if there's another option of copying that range in a way each cell is pasted below the previous one? :(

Comment: You have added VBA as a tag, however, there is not macro code what so ever. it is not 100% clear what you are asking for but do you want to do this with a macro?

Comment: Exactly Aldert, I want to be able to copy Column C in a way I can paste it elsewhere, with linebreaks, and not like; cell1 cell2 cell 3 in the same line, you know?

Using VBA or any other method/alternative is welcome